# PostgreSQL Age Calculation from date type

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.employees
(
employee_id integer NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
date_of_birth date,
address text,
email text,
CONSTRAINT employees_pkey PRIMARY KEY (employees_id),
CONSTRAINT employees_email_key UNIQUE (email)
)
```

How would I be able to list each employee's name with their age in the output?

Thanks.

Comment: There is an age function which is used to calculate age by passing the parameter. select employee_id, name, age(date_of_birth) from employees.

Comment: The `age()` function is documented  here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use date_part() and age() functions

```
SELECT name text, date_part('year',age(date_of_birth)),* FROM public.employees
```

See for documentation of date functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks, was just confused on the date_part, but you helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 13):

you can use `age()` function like this :

```
SELECT name, EXTRACT(year FROM age(current_date,date_of_birth)) :: int as age FROM public.employees
```

Comment: could be used without `current date` with just the field only (ex. `age(date_of_birth)`), anyway it works and that's awesome!

Comment: also you can use `age('2021-01-01', date_of_birth)`