# Rails 6 APi Filter the users age from User Date of Birth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am working on Rails 6 API.

I have @users array and each user is having the date of birth(dob).

I want the filter to user age on the user's array but I want to process that in one query, with the helper method to find the age from date of birth and also compare the filter age parameter.

Here, age might be the simple number and also the range like less than 18, greater than 18 or number 18

I have the Helper method to get the age from DOB

```
 def user_age(dob)
      now = Time.now.utc.to_date
      now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
 end
```

Can I pass it to the query like

```
age = params[:filter][:age]
@users = @users.joins(:user_profile).where(user_age('user.dob') == age) if age.present?
```

It is not working

Comment: Why not just `.order(dob: :desc)` or `.order(dob: :asc)` depending on if you want to get the older users first or last.

Comment: I need to compare the passed age with the users database where each user is having the dob. Here I need to first get the users age and compare it in one query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Age Calculation from date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072914/postgresql-age-calculation-from-date-type)

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the `where` clause must not reference a method on the model. I suggest you convert the threshold age (against which you wish to compare the users' age) to a threshold dob and perform the query like this:

```rb
@users = User.where("users.dob < ?", Date.today.advance(years: -age))
```

This will give you users older than the threshold age. You can tweak it if you are interested in users younger than the threshold age.