# POSTGRES: How to calculate age from dob in a DB that allows only select statements (no data manipulation)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My table looks like this:

| Name | Date of Birth |
| --- | --- |
| John | 02-02-1990 15:30 |
| Esther | 05-05-1980 13:30 |
| Mark | 07-10-1980 12:30 |

I want a query that returns this.

| Age | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | 1 |
| 43 | 2 |

I've seen other solutions like what we have here [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)

But the db does not allow manipulation of data so only SELECT statements are allowed.

Date of birth is Date & Time data type as DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm.

I'm not very familiar with @declare but I get the following error when I try the solutions in the link:

***DB engine Error
Only SELECT statements are allowed against this database.
This may be triggered by:
Issue 1022 - Database does not allow data manipulation.***

Any suggestions would help. Thanks

Comment: Column Date of Birth data type?

Comment: The solutions in the link you provided use SELECT statements.

Comment: You link to a SQL Server question. Those answers will not work for Postgresql.

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm @jarlh

Comment: What have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? On this site you need to show at least some attempt and solving the issue yourself

Comment: You could use the standard PostgreSQL function AGE() and then count.

Comment: @nickw I've tried some of those solutions in the link but here is what I get when I try them:
DB engine Error
Only SELECT statements are allowed against this database.


This may be triggered by:
Issue 1022 - Database does not allow data manipulation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Age Calculation from date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072914/postgresql-age-calculation-from-date-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AGE and extract the year to get the age in years:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(d)) AS age
     , COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES ('John', '02-02-1990 15:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ)
           , ('Esther', '05-05-1980 13:30')
           , ('Mark', '07-10-1980 12:30')) s(name, d)
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also calculate the age in years for each row, and then perform counts:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date of Birth") AS "Age",
  COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  "Age"
ORDER BY
  "Age";
```

Comment: This can add one year

Comment: This expression give a false answer for 50% of the computed age...